# I need help to understand this subspace topology problem...

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $X=\mathbb{R}^2 - A $ be subsets with subspace topology inherited from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ .Then

1. A is countable dense implies that X is totally disconnected.

2.A is unbounded implies that X is compact.

3.A is open implies that X is compact.

4.A is countable implies that X is path-connected.

Comment: Do we have to choose which of those are true?

Comment: Is this a true/false problem?

Comment: $1$ and $3$ are easy with Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: I can not understand  "A and X be subsets with subspace topology inherited  from the usual topology "

Comment: I meant $2$ and $3$

Comment: 2 and 3 are both false.  For 2), take $A = \mathbb{Z}^{2}$.  For 3), use $A = \cup_{n,m \in \mathbb{Z}} B((n,m),1/2)$.

Comment: @Prabhakaran. it means that the open sets of $A$ are precisely $A\cap U$ where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^2$. Here $\mathbb R^2$ is given the usual topology, which means that the set of all open discs form a basis for this topology.